# How to add custom headers to different pages?

Tags: header-footer, titles

I want to achieve the following effect

[image]

headerwise in LaTeX. To be precise, I want to add custom tiltes (as headers one would assume is easier?) to every top bit of a page that is often in a different font. I have so far been able to get the formating of the rest of the page

[image]

with

```
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0in,%
        left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.75in,bottom=1in,%
        footskip=.25in]{geometry}
```

however, when I try to add the "1 Algebra" (as it is in this example) as a centered header, either the formating or the font go wrong, and moreover, I can't seem to change it for other pages.

If anybody has any ideas on how to approach this I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: So you want **1 Algebra** to be on every page... then, for another "section", you want **2 Other section** to be on every page... you'll start a new "section" on a new page *always*?

Comment: Hi @Werner, thank you for the comment. I want to have 1 Algebra for say 5 pages and then 2 Calculus for say 8 pages. In essence, I want the section to be displayed in the header section for every page which continious the section. I hope that is clearer.

Comment: Nomenclature; a header is above the top of the text area, while a title is usually below.  While LaTeX has built in header support (\markboth, \markright), not to mention fancyhdr, one can also use tikz[overlay, remember picture] or \AddToHook or \AddToHookNext to place text into the margins.  Even negative \vspace or \raisebox can be used at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can add content to the header using [`fancyhdr`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). Below I define `\newsection` to clear the page, update the header in a similar way `\section` would do.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

\newcommand{\newsection}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  \stepcounter{section}%
  \fancyhead[C]{\thesection~#1}% Clear
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\sloppy% Just for this example

\newsection{Algebra}

\lipsum[1-20]

\newsection{Other stuff}

\lipsum[21-50]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Werner for the comment. Do you know how could I change the font size in this method as well as as the positioning of the header on the page?

Comment: @MathsWizzard: You can insert any font changes just before `\thesection` in the definition of `\newsection`. For example, `\fancyhead[C]{\bfseries\large \thesection~#1}`. `\fancyhead[C]` sets the `head`er in the `C`entre of the page (horizontally). You can use `\fancyhead[L]`/`\fancyhead[R]` to set it on the `L`eft/`R`ight.